# Does the relationship $c^ n ±1= 2^{kn−2}d^n$ have solutions in the integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

In a previous question [Can a square number plus 1 become a square?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884715/can-a-square-number-plus-1-become-a-square)
the questioner asked in passing at the end whether $a^n+1$ could ever be a perfect square (for $a \ge 1$ and $n \ge 2$). I provided a partial answer demonstrating that $a^n+1 \neq m^2$ when $a$ is odd. In looking at $a$ being even, I got bogged down.

Here is how far I got. $a^n+1 = m^2$ implies $a^n=(m+1)(m-1)$. If $a=2^kb$ is even (with $b$ being odd), then both $(m+1)$ and $(m-1)$ are even. Two consecutive even numbers have only one factor of $2$ in common, i.e. $\gcd {\frac {(m+1)}{2},\frac {(m-1)}{2} =1}$.

$a^n=2^{kn}b^n$ and one of the factors ($(m+1)$ and $(m-1)$) can be represented as $2c^n$ and the other factor can be represented as $2^{kn-1}d^n$, $c$ and $d$ both odd. The difference between the factors is just $2$, but we don't know *a priori* which factor is the larger, so we can say that $2c^n-2^{kn-1}d^n= \pm 2$. Dividing through by $2$ and rearranging we get $c^n \pm 1=2^{kn-2}d^n$.

I mention here that for $c=d=k=1, n=3$ we get $1+1=2$ deriving from the well known example $2^3+1=3^2$.

I can't find a discussion of this in previously posted questions, and I can't see a way forward from this point.

**My question is:** Other than the one example cited, does the relationship $c^n \pm 1=2^{kn-2}d^n$ have solutions in the integers?

**Added by edit:** Since my question arises from a previous question whether $a^n+1$ can be a perfect square, we can see that $n$ must be odd, since $a^{2j}+1=(a^j)^2+1$ which cannot be a perfect square since no two integer squares differ by $1$. Hence in the context of my question, where the exponent $n$ is the same as in the original question, it must be the case that $n=2j+1$.

Comment: If $n=1$ and $k=2$ you get $c\pm 1=d$ which has lots of solutions. And $3^1+1=2^2$ is a solution to $a^n+1=m^2$ with $a$ odd. I presume you want to exclude the case $n=1$.

Comment: @Mark Bennet You're absolutely correct, and I will edit the post to so reflect.

Comment: $(c,d,n,k)=(-1,-1,3,1)$ is a solution to $c^n-1=2^{kn-2}d^n$.